# Querying mongodb documents using java

Tags: java, mongodb

I am mongodb beginner.

I have ItemName and ItemCategory stored as document. Using Java I want to find all the ItemNames for the ItemCategory passed in the method.

I tried following code but it is not working.

```
public String[] generate(String category) {

    MongoClient mongoClient;
    String temp[] = new String[50001];
    String[] prodName = {};
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    int k=0;
    try {
        mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
        DB db = mongoClient.getDB("test");
        DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("products");
        DBCursor cursor = coll.find();
        BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("ItemCategroy", category);

        cursor = coll.find(query);

        try {
            while (cursor.hasNext()) {
                temp[i++] = (String) cursor.next().get("ItemName");
            }
            for (k = 0; k < temp.length; k++) {
                if (temp[k] == null) {
                    k++;
                } else{
                    prodName[j++]=temp[k];
                } 
            }
            System.out.println("kkk"+k);
            /* for (int j = 0; j < nodeNm.length; j++) {
                System.out.println("printing in jsp " + nodeNm[j]);
            } */
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }

        mongoClient.close();
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return prodName;
}
```

HEre in `generate()` method I am passing `category` and want all the `ItemNames` in an array `prodName` which is returned.

Please suugest.

Answer (score 0):

Can you state what exactly is not working? Do you observe an error or is there simply no match? It might be simply due to the typo in `BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("ItemCategroy", category);` where you probably should write `ItemCategory`.

Besides that, your code looks okay for me but of course we cannot know for sure unless you post a sample document of your collection.

Comment: Sample document looks like-    `{
        "_id" : ObjectId("528f37fdb55099000c5dfedd"),
        "ItemName" : "Item1",
        "ItemCategory" : "Electronics",
        "ItemSubCategory" : "TV",
        "ItemBrand" : "Samsung",
        "ItemSize" : "20",
        "ItemPrice" : "7500"
}`

Comment: okay, so `"ItemCategroy"` indeed is a typo - does fixing it help?